# Как ответ полученный с сервера в Ajax-запросе записать в свойства класса?

Tags: javascript, ajax, ооп, ecmascript-6, xmlhttprequest

Написал класс для работы с Ajax-запросами все работает, только после выполнения метода `GET()` класса `Ajax` необходимо данные полученные с сервера записать в свойства `res` того же класса, но на деле в свойства `res` ничего не записывается, подскажите как это исправить?

```js
class Ajax{
    constructor(url){
        this.res = null;
        this.url = url;
        this.GET(this.url, this.coll);
    }
    GET(url, coll){
        let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('GET', url);
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
                coll(xhr.responseText);
            }
        };
        xhr.send();
    }
    coll(data){
        this.res = data;
    }
}

let aj = new Ajax('php/test.php');
console.log(aj.res);
```

Comment: записывается. Только позже, чем вы пытаетесь его прочитать.Свойство доступно после того, как только вы получите ответ от сервера.

Answer (score 0):

Функция `send()` выполняется асинхронно по умолчанию. Если вы хотите чтобы она ваполнялась синхронно, то надо использовать

```
xhr.open('GET', url, false);
```

но это будет блокировать выполнение скрипта, пока сервер не вернет значение, что следует избегать. Для этого вам надо чтобы ваша функция `GET()` вызывалась асинхронно и возвращала `Promise`. Тогда вы можете

```
let aj = new Ajax('php/test.php');
aj.GET().then(function(res) {
   console.log(aj.res);
});
```

Функцию `GET` нужно переписать

```
GET(url, coll){
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', url);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
            coll(xhr.responseText);
            resolve(xhr.responseText);
        }
    };
    xhr.send();
 });
}
```